# Find vector which spans line defined by two equations

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: q5]

So in a previous question, I succesfully found a pair of vectors which spanned a  plane. However, how do i find a vector which spans a line given by these two equations? Since both equations given are linear, am I supposed to define the subspace they occupy together?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the parametric equation of the line of intersection of these 2 planes, 
That is:
$$x(t)=3t$$
$$y(t)=-t$$
$$z(t)=(7/2)t$$

The vector that spans this line is its directing vector that is here $(3,-1,7/2)$